# css / jquery animation not supported by IE9 - workaround required

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, animation

I have the following animation that doesn't work in **IE9** as the transition property is not supported.

Unfortunately I have to get it working for **IE9+**.

Does anyone know any fix / workaround?

https://jsfiddle.net/jyqkr52q/1/

**CSS**

```
.egg{
    position:absolute;
    left:-120px;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
}
.egg>div{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.egg>div>span{
    background-image:URL('http://leanneoleary.com/test/rollin-animation/Purple_Easter_Egg_small.png');
    position:absolute;
    left:23px;
    top:14px;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:45px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="egg_box">
    <div class="egg">
        <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $egg = $('#egg_box > div'),
    diameter = $egg.height(),
    perimeter = Math.PI * diameter,
    n = $egg.length,
    i = 0,
    itv;

itv = setInterval(function(){
    if(i>n)clearInterval(itv);
    rotateegg( 500-(diameter*i) );
    i++;
},2000);

function rotateegg(distance){
    console.log( distance );
    var degree = distance * 360 / perimeter;
    $egg.eq(i).css({
        transition: "2s cubic-bezier(1.000, 1.450, 0.185, 0.850)",
        transform: 'translateX('+ distance +'px)'
    }).find('div').css({
        transition: "2s cubic-bezier(1.000, 1.450, 0.185, 0.850)",
        transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'  
    });
}
```

Comment: Check transition browser support. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/ It only support IE 10+

Comment: CSS3 is not supported in IE9.

Comment: Yes I know its not supported, I was asking if anyone knew of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Transition property is not supported in IE 9.0, it is supported from IE 10 onwards.so your animation is not working on IE 9.0.

[image]

But CSS3 transform property is supported from IE 9.0 onwards.

[Official MDN Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: OK so what exactly would I need to change in the code to get this working using the transform property instead of the transition?

Comment: Transform and transition are completely different, there is no way you can use transition property in IE 9.0. one alternative is that you can use jquery's `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` effect thats the only transition there is for IE 9.0